# Cannot copy draggable element unless sibling is clicked first

Tags: javascript, html, copy-paste

If an element with a copy event bound to it has an element with draggable inside of it, the copy event is not fired unless you first click on a non-draggable sibling.

Here is the code:

```html
<div id='copy'>
  <div draggable='true'>Draggable</div>
  <div>Non-draggable</div>
</div>
```

```js
const copy = document.getElementById('copy');

copy.addEventListener('copy', (e) => {
    alert('copied');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pg4f0usx/

Replication steps:

- Run the fiddle
- Click on the draggable element and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> - nothing will happen
- Click on the non-draggable element and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> - the 'copied' alert will pop up
- Click on the draggable element and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> - the 'copied' alert will pop up

This happens in both FireFox and Chrome.  Is there a way to avoid needing to click on the non-draggable element for the copy event to be fired on the parent element?

Comment: It seems logic, in my opinion, when you click on a draggable, you want to drag it somewhere else, you won't be able to select its content

Comment: It's inconsistent though - if you click on the non-draggable element, the draggable element starts allowing you to copy.

Comment: I don't think so, maybe the select cursor stayed at the position in the non-draggable and you can ctrl+c. Paste the copied value and you will see

Comment: I'm using a custom copy event - I'm not actually attempting to copy any data from either element.  https://jsfiddle.net/mtpxf9ry/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach the copy event in the window so that you don't need to click on that `div`. But you need to be in that window (at least clicking somewhere)

```js
    window.addEventListener('copy', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'copied data');
      alert('copied');
    });
```

```html
<div id='copy'>
      <div draggable='true'>Draggable</div>
      <div>Non-draggable</div>
</div>
<div id='outro'>
  <span style='background-color:gray; align-items: center; padding:50px; padding-top: 0px; '>If you are anywhere in the page (like here)  it will copy with CTRL + C</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Although this doesn't directly solve the issue (you would run into problems if you needed to copy text elsewhere in the page), the way I have my copy set up I can use the document focus to check what they're attempting to copy, so this works for me.